# Issue installing jhipster-uml

Tags: node.js, npm, jhipster

Using windows 10 when I run the command `npm install -g jhipster-uml` I have the following error:

```
C:\Users\Talon\AppData\Roaming\npm\jhipster-uml -> C:\Users\Talon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jhipster-uml\jhipster-uml.js

> deasync@0.1.9 install C:\Users\Talon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jhipster-uml\node_modules\deasync
> node ./build.js


C:\Users\Talon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jhipster-uml\node_modules\deasync>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Talon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jhipster-uml\node_modules\deasync
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! deasync@0.1.9 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the deasync@0.1.9 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Talon\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-11T14_51_34_388Z-debug.log
```

Googling around it seems to be a Windows issue with `npm_config_node_gyp`. I tried using npm cli to install other packages and it works, so it's most likely an issue with jhipster-uml.

I also tried using yarn to install it, I have a really similar error.

Answer (score 0):

> > Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.

1. You have to install python and restart the bash
2. If python is already installed, check if it's available in your PATH. If no, just add it.